# Why do we need kafka to feed data to apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am reading about `spark` and its `real-time stream` processing.I am confused that If `spark` can itself read stream from source such as **twitter** or **file**, then Why do we need `kafka` to feed data to `spark`? It would be great if someone explains me what advantage we get if we use `spark` with `kafka`. Thank you.

Comment: You don't *need* it-they serve different purposes. Kafka presents a unified source to consume is all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Kafka offers a decoupling and buffering of your input stream.

Take Twitter data for example, afaik you connect to the twitter api and get a constant stream of tweets that match criteria you specified. If you now shut down your Spark jobs for an hour do to some mainentance on your servers or roll out a new version, then you will miss tweets from that hour.

Now imagine you put Kafka in front of your Spark jobs and have a very simple ingest thread that does nothing but connect to the api and write tweets to Kafka, where the Spark jobs retrieve them from. Since Kafka persists everything to disc, you can shut down your processing jobs, perform maintenance and when they are restarted, they will retrieve all data from the time they were offline.

Also, if you change your processing jobs in a significant way and want to reprocess data from the last week, you can easily do that if you have Kafka in your chain (provided you set your retention time high enough) - you'd simply roll out your new jobs and change the offsets in Kafka so that your jobs reread old data and once that is done your data store is up to date with your new processing model.

There is a [good article](https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/questioning-the-lambda-architecture) on the general principle written by Jay Kreps, one of the people behind Kafka, give that a read if you want to know more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It makes sense to me. I just have one more question regarding repoducing data from last week as you said. What if we are storing the data in HDFS as well. In that case, kafka purpose is to hold data only when system is down, right? I'm actually discussing in the sense of lambda architecture. In serving layer we can use data from hadoop and kafka will hold the new data. Is it correct? Thank you.

Comment: you could use Spark streaming with the HDFS input, processing new files from a specified dir. However, it will be much harder to control re-processing from a specific point in time  - you'd have to muck around with moving files between HDFS directories.... With Kafka, you can specify from what position (offset) you can start processing your data. Also, if your Spark job is long-running - the files housekeeping may become an issue - you probably won't want to have millions of files in the same input HDFS dir, I assume. You have to design a process to delete/move old files or such.

Comment: Depends a bit on how you put the data in HDFS, you can write into a staging dir and from there regularly run an Oozie job to insert the data into a partitioned Hive table, that way Hive would take care of your underlying file organization and you have an easy way of reprocessing data in batch (provided they have a timestamp, which I assume) and even of deleting old data.
There really is no right or wrong way here, it all depends heavily on what exactly your requirements are :)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the explanation. However, I have one question. How does it work if you need to maintain kafka itself?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka decouples everything,Consumer-Producer need not to know about each other.
Kafka provides pub-sub model based on topic.

From multiple sources you can write data(messages) to any topic in kafka, and consumer(spark or anything) can consume data based on topic.

Multiple consumer can consume data from same topic as kafka stores data for period of time.

But at the end, it's depends ion your use-case if you really need a broker.